# self-study: Basic algebra.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This is from a book I'm reading as self-study. Every once in awhile I run into a problem I just don't know how to do. The following is such a problem. We are given the answer, but the precise work isn't shown. Here it is:

$$\frac{34}{m} - \frac12 = \frac{34 \cdot 4}{4m + 1}$$

which yields,

$$68 + 271m - 4m^2 = 272m$$

I can't discover the steps that lead to that answer....

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Your two equations are not equivalent.

Comment: Here's a start for user102401 to check it him/herself: Are you familiar with statements like $a=\frac{b}{c} \implies ca=c\left(\frac{b}{c}\right)=b$?

Comment: Yes, I get that, it is just when I try to work out the "nut and bolts" of the transformation, I can't seem to arrive at what the author does.

Answer (score 2):

I take it that the book gives the answer as $68-271m-4m^2=272m$; this is a typo. If you’re getting $68+271m-4m^2=272m$, you’re right.

Answer (score 1):

When working with an algebraic equation over $\Bbb{R}$ (i.e. the variables take values in $\Bbb{R}$ ), you have these properties:

$$
\begin{align*}
&(1) \ \ \forall c \in \Bbb{R}, \ a = b \iff a + c = b + c \\
&(2) \ \ \forall c \neq 0 \in \Bbb{R}, \ a = b \iff ac = bc \\
&(3) \ \ \forall a,b,c \in \Bbb{R}, \ a (b + c) = ab + bc
\end{align*}
$$
where
$ \forall$ means *for all* and $\iff$ means *if and only if*, which is used since the operation by $c$ is reversible, right?

Also, note the the numbers involved $(a,b,c)$ can be expressions as well, you just have to becareful to handle the case when $c$ may equal $0$ in property $(2)$.

Now back to your equation:

$$
(34 / m) - (1/2) = (34 * 4) / (4m + 1)
$$

The problem implicitly assumes that $m \neq 0$ and $4m + 1 \neq 0$ or the expressions involving those would be undefined (you can't define $a / 0$ in any useable way).

Thus we may multiply both sides by $m$ and $4m + 1$, yielding:

$$
34(4m + 1) - (1/2)m(4m + 1) = 34*4 m
$$

Now use $(3)$, the distributive property, to expand these expressions in parentheses:
$$
34*4 m + 34 - 2m^2 - 1/2 m = 34*4m
$$

Then we obviously have a number on both sides we can use $(1)$, thus 'cancelling out' the $34*4m$ to get:
$$
34 - 2m^2 - 1/2 m = 0
$$

Not really necessary but we can change all the coefficients to integers by multiplying by $2$ to yield:
$$
68 - 4m^2 - m = 0
$$

Note that between each of the above equations that we worked on we can throw an $\iff$, an *if and only if* since the operation is reversible.  So in other words, your original equation has solution $m$ **iff** the resulting equation has the same solution $m$.  So finding all solutions to the latter gives you all solutions to the former.

Comment: "Thus we may multiply both sides by m and 4m+1"  thus giving a common denominator, man do I feel stupid. Thanks for helping!

Comment: I'm not sure if my arithmetic adds up - it's not matching you alls' above.

Comment: Seems to match to me.....